# Unions? NABET verses MPEG

Tags: untagged

I finished all my required classes and paperwork in order to be rostered on the MPEG 700 as a Y-1 and then got a call for a union gig on lot.  However, it appears this lot and gig are NABET, not MPEG.

In DC, I was briefly an IATSE member so I could work on a video for the Airline Pilots Union.  They didn't care if I was a member of their union. I just had to be a member of a union. Is this how is works out here or do I seriously have to go through the whole process again for NABET and pay separate dues?

I mean, I will....and I am stoked to have a union gig for a bit. But, it would be nice not to have to go through a whole process again....

Has anyone else had this experience?